# Column replacement in 2D array Python (not numpy)

Tags: python, arrays, generator

I have a dumn question:

I have an array, for example
`x = [[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1]]`

in the case of
`x[1][:] = [9 if x[1][k] == 1 else 0 for k in range(3)]`

I will get
`[[1, 1, 1], [9, 9, 9], [1, 1, 1]]`

but in the case of
`x[:][1] = [9 if x[k][1] == 1 else 0 for k in range(3)]`

I will get
`[[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1]]`

Why?

In the case of numpy this is not a problem and everything works, but why this is a problem in the case of original Python?

Comment: Why not? What did you expect? [ask] and [mre]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How slicing in Python works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/how-slicing-in-python-works)

Comment: You are not modifying `x` in-place but assigning `[9, 9, 9]` to the second element of a copy of it: `x[:]`.

Answer (score 0):

you'll have the same behaviour with any other assignment:

```
x[:][1] = 'hello'
print(x) # unchanged
```

this is because you are assigning to a copy of `x` (this is not numpy so `x[:]` is not a view but a copy) which you don't hold and gets discarded immediately.

What you are doing is equivalent to:

```
y = x[:]
assert id(x) != id(y)
y[1] = 'hello'

print(x) # unchanged
print(y) # changed
```